# TV or Monitor for store showcase

Tags: display, tv

I want to embellish my shop showcase with a TV or Monitor. Basically to 'project' presentations ( '.ppt', pictures, perhaps videos )

The showcase is in street side usually at shadow. Signal will be via HDMI connector. Size is not a problem, from 24'' or 32''.

What can be a good technology/product for this kind of purpose? What about pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between modern TVs and monitors is the viewing distance they are designed for. Monitors have a higher pixels per inch density so test looks nice when you are sitting two feet away, TVs have larger surface area for viewing at long distances.

If you are going to be presenting small details on the screen and you expect people to lean up close to view the details go buy a high resolution monitor, if you are just displaying some large text and/or images a TV would work fine.

Comment: *"The only difference between modern TVs and monitors is the viewing distance"* -- Wrong.  TVs must have a tuner, computer monitor = no tuner.  Computer monitor will accept more resolutions (e.g. VESA standards) and scale to native if necessary.  Computer monitor will not overscan.  BTW there is more than one kind of "monitor" e.g. computer, video, broadcast, studio (could be a speaker or a display).